# I want to delete a row in a listview using a button in that row without cursor.requery as it is depreciated

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor, android-cursoradapter

I am using a CursorAdapter with 3 TextViews and 1 button. I want to delete the entry from my database when I hit the button.
Note: There exists many posts on this, however they all suggest the same code using the now depreciated "cursor.requery"

```
@Override
public void bindView(View view, final Context context, final Cursor cursor) {

    TextView viewID = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.viewID);
    TextView viewAmount=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.viewAmount);
    TextView viewCategory=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.viewCategory);
    Button buttonDelete = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonDelete);

    final int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id"));
    String amount = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("amount"));
    String category = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("category"));

    viewID.setText(String.valueOf(id));
    viewAmount.setText(amount);
    viewCategory.setText(category);

    buttonDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Deleted item " + id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //Do I create a DB handler here and run a dbHandler.deleteItem(id)   
            //method or do something else?    

            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one

```
buttonDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Deleted item " + id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            String query = "DELETE * from *table_name* where _id = "+ id + "";
            db.execQuery(query) // db is your DatabaseHelper  
            startActivity(getIntent()); 
            finish();                
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: So I ran a db.deleteTransaction(id); line since I have the query in my dbHandler and it did in fact delete the transaction.   
However: (1) It did not refresh the table and I had to manually go to the previous page and return for the change to take effect and (2) I thought it's bad to run an SQL query in the CustomAdapter class as this class runs very frequently.

Comment: just intent your activity after deleting your selected row :)

Comment: So I added an intent that reran the activity with the listview and it does work in the sense that an item is deleted and the screen changes to reflect the new dataset. However it's not "refreshing" but rather creating a "new" screen. This means that When I hit the back button on my phone, it'll go back to the screen before the delete happened... containing the delete row.

Comment: just change the position of finish and startActivity. You need to intent first then finish your activity :)

Comment: It helped lead me in the right direction, thanks for that. For other people looking at this, note that I went back and looked up how to use content providers and cursor loaders and implemented the solution with that. I would highly recommend you use those systems as well since it made my life and my code much easier after I learned it.